# reading secret for JWT signing from k8s secret in Micronaut

Tags: java, configuration, jwt, micronaut

Our services rely on Micronauts built-in JWT funtionality for Authorization, when testing we've just left the default settings, but as we're getting ready to go live, we need to set up a more proper secrets management. We're deploying in a Kubernetes environment and so we have decided to store all secret as k8s Secrets. I've been trying (and failing) to configure Micronaut to use these secrets for signing and verifying tokens.

Following the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#jwtGeneratorSignature)

> To enable a JWT signature in token generation, you need to have in your app a bean of type RSASignatureGeneratorConfiguration, ECSignatureGeneratorConfiguration, SecretSignatureConfiguration qualified with name generator.

I ended up with the following:

```java
@Singleton
@Named("generator")
public class MinecraftSecretSignatureConfiguration extends SecretSignatureConfiguration {
    @Inject
    public MinecraftSecretSignatureConfiguration(KeyPairProvider keyPairProvider) {
        super("generator");
        //KeyPairProvider.readSecret reads the secret and returns it as a string starting with ------BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-------
        setSecret(keyPairProvider.readSecret().blockingGet());
        setBase64(false);
        setJwsAlgorithm(JWSAlgorithm.HS256);
    }
}
```

but it appears this config is not used, the tokens are not signed and when setting breakpoints in this class they are never reached. What am I missing?

Comment: did you find a solution for it?

Comment: I did! I'll try to remember to write up a response to this question when I have the time, and share my findings with the community. thanks for reminding me, I had forgotten I had asked this question

Comment: having difficulties finding the time to do a write-up, but as it turns out micronaut has now added built-in kubernetes support! My solution was home-rolled, but these days you don't have to, you shoud probably follow https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kubernetes/snapshot/guide/ instead